# Как добавить UIView в качестве Map Object на карту Yandex Map Kit 3.0

Tags: ios, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, mobile, yandexmapkit

я сейчас осуществляю переход Yandex Map Kit Mobile SDK с 1.0.11 на 3.0.0

Раньше мы использовали в приложении объект аннотации типа YMKAnnotationView. Сейчас возникают сложности с добавлением их на новую карту. Не нашел в API библиотеки как можно добавить UIView в качестве MapObject'а.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

В новой версии 3.1 это стало возможно с помощью:

```
let view = YRTViewProvider(uiView: callout)
```

Но почему то оно не поддерживает прозрачность. Лучше воспользоваться другим методом.

Через `UIImageView`:

```
private func convertViewToImage(_ view: UIView) -> UIImage? {

    let size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height + 20)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    if let aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        view.layer.render(in: aContext)
    }
    let img: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img
}


placemark = mapObjects.addPlacemark(with: point, image: convertViewToImage(callout)!, style: style)
placemark.opacity = 1
placemark.zIndex = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Хочу дополнить ответ *Алексея Левинтова*, 
 если вы решили использовать `YRTViewProvider(uiView: callout)`, то прозрачность можно получить так:

```
view.isOpaque = false
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
```

**Источник решения**: https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo/issues/28